# Azure App Service Cannot connect to restored Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I had restored an Azure SQL DB from .bacpac from Azure Storage..
I can connect successfully and access all object from SSMS 2019.
But my Azure App Service throws error, Login failed for 'user..XXXX'

I have given permission for "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" on the Azure DB server.

How do I troubleshoot or fix the problem ?

FYI:
I can connect successfully from SSMS and do all the operation.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'XXXXXXAppUser'.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
ClientConnectionId:XXXXXXXX-1e0a5b65dd11
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
ClientConnectionId before routing:XXXXXXXX-c3154c7b1c61
Routing Destination:XXXXXXXXX.tr2023.northcentralus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11002
```

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned error could be because of multiple reasons, therefore I suggest you to **look into the error logs to see what the exact reason for the login failure.** I guess either the database name or password is misspelled.

However, the exact issue seems like with the format of your password. Your password might containing some special character like '$', due to which when you pass your password as command it is reading it as some parameter starting with '$' as a command and it read half of your password string as a different value.

**Solution:** Either create another user with simple normal password (without containing '$' symbol), or change the password of the existing user.

Comment: I don't have $ symbol in username or password. 
Also i can connect and do all operations without problem when connecting from SSMS.